# Rollback of new column deletes the entire table

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to rollback updated column in my database table using migrations in laravel 4.2.

```
public function up()
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('payments') && !Schema::hasColumn('payments', 'updated_at')) {

        Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('payments')) {

        Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            Schema::drop('updated_at');
        });
    }
}
```

When I do it this way it shows me that `updated_at` table doesnt exist:

```
Schema::drop('updated_at');
```

Doing it this way deleted the entire table:

```
Schema::drop('payments', 'updated_at');
```

How is it supposed to look like then?

Thank you and best wishes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Schema::drop('updated_at');` is telling the DB to drop the `updated_at` table, which obviously doesn't exist. You need to use `$table->dropColumn('updated_at')` to drop a column on a specific table. See below:

```
public function down(){
    if (Schema::hasTable('payments')) {
        Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('updated_at');
        });
    }
}
```

You can see you are already in the `Schema::table("payments" ...)` function, so using `$table->dropColumn()` will attempt to drop the column from the payment table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$table` variable:

```
Schema::table('payments', function($table)
{
    $table->dropColumn('updated_at');
});
```